# Mixin background gradient with background image.png

Tags: sass, background

I have a mixin declared more or less like this

```
@mixin color-background {
  background: yellow;
}
```

And i would wish to use this color as background of a png. but i cant seem to be able to mix the two

now what i would like to do is for example

```
.myImageWithBackgroundColor{
    background: url(image.png),@include color-background
}
```

How can i acheive this with SASS and mixin?

Comment: What's the purpose of the mixin? That would help us figure out how to best help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the background value of the mixin to a variable, and then use the variable instead of the whole mixin in the second code snippet.

```
$my-color: yellow;

@mixin color-background {
    background: $my-color;
}

.myImageWithBackgroundColor{
    background: url(image.png) $my-color;
}
```